# How to add quantity dropdown in cart for configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, cart, configurable-product

Hello
I am using magento 1.7.0.2 CE. I need to display a dropdown for product quantity to allow a user to select quantity from the dropdown on cart page. I have added a code in `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` for the same which is,

```
<?php echo $min_sale_qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($this->getProduct())->getData('min_sale_qty');
 $total_qyt = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($this->getProduct())->getQty();
     ?>
    <select name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]">
    <?php for($i = $min_sale_qty; $i <= $total_qyt; $i = $i + $min_sale_qty)
      {
      ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>" <?php echo ($i == $this->getQty())? "selected=selected": ""; ?>>
      <?php echo $i?>
    </option>
   <?php }?> 
   </select>
```

This code displays the dropdown correctly for simple products. But when I add configurable product to my cart, It displays me dropdown without any option to select.
Can anyone help me with it? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tested and this works for me.

```
    $simpleProduct = $this->getProduct();
    if ($this->getProduct()->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
        foreach ($_item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $simpleItem){
            if ($simpleItem->getParentItemId() == $_item->getId()){
                $simpleProduct = $simpleItem->getProduct();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleProduct);
    $min_sale_qty = (int)$stockItem->getData('min_sale_qty');
    $total_qyt = (int)$stockItem->getQty();

    ?>
    <select name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]">
        <?php for($i = $min_sale_qty; $i <= $total_qyt; $i = $i + $min_sale_qty) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i?>" <?php echo ($i == $this->getQty())? "selected=selected": ""; ?>>
                <?php echo $i?>
            </option>
        <?php endfor;?>
    </select>
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Step :1  Go to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product**/view/addtocart.phtml

In the addtocart.phtml file find the following code(around line 33)

```
<input name="qty" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" />



Replace with this code:

This code shows the “Available Qty for Product”.
<select class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty">
  <?php $i = 1 ?>
  <?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
      <?php echo $i?>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()) ?></select>


**This code shows the “Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart”.**

<select class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty">
  <?php $i = 1 ?>
  <?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
      <?php echo $i?>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getMaxSaleQty()) ?></select>
```

Hope you'll solve your problem.